# Visual Studio, C++, using a DLL exported class in another DLL exported class

Tags: c++, class, dll, import, export

I am playing around with Visual Studio and I found an error I cannot understand.
I created a DLL exporting a Class; if I create another DLL project and I try to use the first DLL class as a member variable it doesn't work depending on how I declare it.

This is the first DLL class:

```
class LOCKING_API CCriticalSection {
public:
    CCriticalSection(void);
    ~CCriticalSection(void);
    void Enter(void);
    void Leave(void);
    BOOL TryEnter(void);
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;
};
```

In the second DLL:

```
#include "../Locking/Locking.h"

class APPLICATION_API CApplication {
public:
    static CApplication* instance(void);
private:
    CApplication(void);
    static CApplication* pInstance;
    static CCriticalSection CritSect;
};
```

If I try to compile I get the error:

```
Application.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class CCriticalSection CApplication::CritSect" (?CritSect@CApplication@@0VCCriticalSection@@A)
```

Comment: How are you linking in the first DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not initializing the static members of `CApplication`. In one of your cpp files, have:

```
CCriticalSection CApplication::CritSect;
```

(and do the same with `pInstance`, of course)

Edit:

Another possibility is that you're not linking to the lib file of your first DLL in the project of your second DLL. If that's the case, the compiler sees `CCriticalSection`'s declaration, but the linker can't find its implementation. See [.Lib Files as Linker Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I am still a noob. Somehow i thought to initialize only variables (i indeed initialized pInstance using CApplication* CApplication::pInstance = 0;) and not the CCriticalSection object.